# How to pass ajax variable to another page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have no idea how to pass variable to another page using ajax. I wish to get data from Page1 and echo in Page2.
Here is my code:

**Page 1**

```
<?=
   formDropdown('employeeName', 'employeeName', 'Employee Name:', $empName,
   isset($employeeName) ? '' : $hiddenV , 'All', '', 'onchange="employeeNameChange(this.value)"', 'form-control', '<br>');
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
function employeeNameChange(str) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "indexPage.php",
        data: "en=" + str,
        success: function(data){
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

**Page 2**

```
$emp_name = $_POST['en'];
echo "Employee Name is ". $_POST['en'] ;
```

When I echo the message, output is "Employee Name is   ". Why is that?

Comment: From my experience in ajax, it will be quite hard to display it from `page2.php`, because when you echo it, it is passed on in `success`, or you will be returned with an error if it is an invalid return *(it will be based from your chosen `dataType`)*

Comment: There is nothing here that suggests that you should have any output at all. What does your form look like (the complete html) and where do you see output?

Comment: Probably `str` contains empty string

Comment: How do you check the result of page2.php on your ajax call, since you don't use any callback? With browsers developers tools? Just asking because you look new to ajax. If you try to display page2 after your ajax call then this is the error because it is a different call than the ajax one with new parameters

Comment: As other have commented; Page 2 needs to be indexPage.php and response will be available in the `success` callback as `data`.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the variable is defined, you can try this to check if it really contains something

```
function employeeNameChange(str) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "indexPage.php",
        data: "en=" + str,
        dataType:"text",
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);
        },
        error:function(xhr, status, error){
            alert(error);
        }
    });
}
```

And in `indexPage.php`

```
if(isset($_POST['en'])){
    echo $_POST['en'];
}
```

This should alert the value of `str`, or alert an error

Comment: I get the output : Internal Server Error